# keras save serialised weights, HDF5, to AWS s3 using python

Tags: amazon-s3, keras, save, hdf5

I am running an LSTM model in keras in python and it saves the model and weights separately into local drive, using the code shown below. What is the coding to save it to AWS S3 bucket?

````
model.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch, verbose=2)
            architecture = model.to_json()
with open('folder/filename.json', 'wt') as json_file:
          json_file.write(architecture)

# serialises weights and saves hdf5
model.save_weights('folder/filename.h5')```
````